# Can I execute interactive command from program?

Tags: node.js

I would like to execute command from program.

```
const child_process = require("child_process")

const data = parseConfigFile("/path/to/config.json")
const {command, param1, param2, args} = convert(data)

child_process.exec(
    `${command} --param1=${param1} --param2=${param2} ${args.join(" ")}`
)
```

It works fine if `command` is not interactive command such as `node file.js`, `cp a.txt b.txt`, or etc...

However, if `command` is interactive command such as `psql`, `php -a`, `parted`, or etc..., it does not work.
I think that it is necessary to connect the stdin and stdout to the child process.
Can I execute interactive command from program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, to do it you have to intercept stdio and stderr streams.

- See examples and instructions here: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin
- Also notice that there are a lot of npm modules providing shell commands access